# Excluding one column from forEach

Tags: foreach, openrefine

I'm using the following expression to return an md5 hash of a concatenation of all values in a row.

```
md5(forEach(row.columnNames,cn,if(isNull(cells[cn]),"",cells[cn].value)).join("|"))
```

This is to create an easy index for identifying duplicates (I do not wish to remove them at this stage). However, I've just realised that because one of the columns contains the unique index for the data set, I cannot hash every column as the inclusion of this column will obviously make every hash unique! (duh)

Is there a way to exclude a nominated column from the forEach loop? A sort of forEach except this...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the column you want to exclude is the first one, you can subset `row.columnNames` like this:

```
md5(forEach(row.columnNames.slice(1),cn,if(isNull(cells[cn]),"",cells[cn].value)).join("|"))
```

If you prefer to exclude a column by its name (for example, "ID"), you should use `filter()` :

```
md5(forEach(filter(row.columnNames, v, v!="ID"),cn,if(isNull(cells[cn]),"",cells[cn].value)).join("|"))
```

Similarly, you can also use `filter()`to include/exclude column names based on conditions (here : exclude columns that contain a capital "C" in their name):

```
filter(row.columnNames, v, v.contains("C")==false)
```

Comment: Brilliant! All solutions worked perfectly and thanks for including both options.